# Paginator (In BackGrid) - css/image for page left and page right?

Tags: css, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, backgrid

I'm using BackGrid.js to paginate my data tables but I'm having a small issue with css on the "page left" and "page right" images, they don't seem to be rendering for me so I must either be missing the releant images or I don't have the relevant css on the elements in question,

Iv tried to look around for a solution/example of how they are rendered but have come unstuck (loked at twitter bootstraps version of this also to see if that would help style it), image is here:

[image]

As you can see there should be arrows point to the left of "page 1" and to the right of "page 10"

Any help much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

backgrid-paginator.js does actually set these values. The way i got around it was to remove the characters defined under fastForwardLabels and replace with my own simple arrows:

```
  /** @property */
    fastForwardHandleLabels: {
      first: "<<",
      prev: "<",
      next: ">",
      last: ">>"
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use an unicode font such as Arial and set your character encoding to utf-8 (as you should at all times) to see the arrows. You can also [override](http://backgridjs.com/#api-paginator) the [fast forward handles](http://backgridjs.com/api/index.html#!/api/Backgrid.Extension.Paginator) too.

Comment: Cheers - bit of a stupid question but am i right in saying the font should be set in my css? I was having difficulty finding out the element names for the page left/right arrows

Comment: Backgrid doesn't actually set any font for you. You can just set it in the body's CSS.